# how to Convert EST time to IST time in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a requirement where I get the data in Excel column like "7/12/2017 3:00:00 AM" (EST timing). Now I need to convert it into IST time of the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Indian Standard Time** is `9 hours and 30 minutes` ahead of **Eastern Time**, use the following formula

```
=A1+TIME(9,30,0)
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: HI You code only adds hours to the time but i need with day also

Comment: @AmarReddy - I've added image for reference. It's working for me. Which `DATE` format are you using?

Comment: @AmarReddy - Both columns should be of same date format.

Comment: @AmarReddy - If you are not able to make it work is it possible for you to share your file with sample/dummy data.

Comment: The only difference between i have data like 7/13/17 2:00 AM  you have 7-13-17 2:00 MA